# Rails Quick and simple way to check valid URL (not format, but actual link)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, http, routes

I am setting `session[:return_to]` for a lot of my routes to take users back to where they were before. I'm trying to create a generic checker to make sure that the link is valid, not the format, (`http://somevalidurl`) I don't care about that but that the actual link exists.

The main problem is when they are on a `show` page and then go to the `edit` page and delete an entry, the `return_to` takes them back to `show` page and we get a routing error because the entry no longer exists.

I would think that Rails had some sort of system for this in place.

I have something like this:

```
Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(session[:return_to])) rescue false
```

But that takes forever to check and the page ends up taking a long time to refresh.

Ideas are welcome.

Comment: Maybe before you destroy the record you should make sure that `return_to` points somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking if a previous url is valid is unnecessary, because such cases are not common routes to use your app. They are just exceptions. You only need a plan when exceptions happens, instead of dealing with it in every common route.

Simple solution: redirect to root

```
class ApplicationController
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :record_not_found

  private
  def record_not_found
    redirect_to root_path, alert: "The record does not exist"
  end
end
```

Advanced solution: redirect to controller's index page

```
class ApplicationController
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |exception|
    # The message like: "Couldn't find foo with id=123"
    klass = exception.message.split(' ')[2]
    if klass
       # suppose your index path is conventional foos_path
       path = send "#{klass.pluralize.underscore}_path"
    else
       path = root_path
    end
    redirect_to path
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this almost did it, but the redirection path is being interpreted literally (as a string instead of the path itself), that is I see this in the logs: `Redirected to http://localhost:3000books_path` when I would expect `books_path` to actually be `books`. I can edit it to include the class name, etc but would like to know how to fix it properly.

Comment: @kakubei, ah, yes, I forget to add `send`, answer revised.

Comment: Excellent! I had used `path = "/#{klass.pluralize.downcase}"` but this is much nicer. Thanks!